# .htaccess - multiple parameters doesn't seem to work

Tags: .htaccess

trying to do the following:

```
link.com/profil/2/cv/ret/slet-1
```

to

```
link.com/profil.php?id=2&do=cv&task=ret&action=slet&aid=1
```

My RewriteRule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^profil/([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)-([d]+)$ profil.php?id=$1&do=$2&task=$3&action=$4&aid=$5
```

It's returning to my /404 page.

**UPDATE**

Looks like it's because of the [d]+ - I've used .* and now it's working. How come it's like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `"\"` while matching the last digit. Change your regex to

```
^profil/([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)-([\d]+)$
```